# Call a batch from another batch file, and set the inner batch files parameters from the outer batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, cmd, parameter-passing

So I have no idea if this is possible, but I want to be able to call an inner batch, from an outer batch, and be able to set parameters inside the inner batch using the outer batch. For example the outer batch file has `outerParam1`, `outerParam2`, `outerParam3`. Then in the inner batch file, it sets its own `param1`, `param2`, `param3` equal to the outer batch file versions.

Comment: please take a look at `call /?`

Comment: @DennisvanGils yes I know I can call a batch inside another batch, but I want to know how to pass the batch that is being called parameters.

Comment: as `call /?` tells you, you can use `call somefile.bat %outerParam1%`, and then use `%1 to` get that value in somefile.bat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In batchfiles, you can call another batch-file with parameters by simply adding them after the filename with spaces between them. For example you could have something like this;

outerbatch.bat:

```
@echo off
set "outerParam1=hello world"
set "outerParam2=!"
call innerbatch.bat "%outerParam1%" "%outerParam2%"
```

innerbatch.bat:

```
@echo off
set "param1=%~1"
set "param2=%~2"
echo %param1% %param2%
pause
```

This will make innerbatch.bat echo:

> hello world

Comment: Worked, although I do have one parameter that has spaces in it, and it is causing problems. For example if the parameter was "hello world" it thinks it is "hello". Although, this might be a problem with getting variables from text files. Thoughts?